# How to get same response time in jmeter report and network tab of that api

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0

How to get same response time in  jmeter report and network tab. when we execute one api in jmeter which we got from network tab, the response time is varying in chrome network tab and in jmeter aggregate report. In network tab it's taking approximately 1.4s to execute, but in jmeter it's taking 3 to 4 sec to execute for same request. Why that much execution time is different. How to analyze that

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is due to [caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) as the browser takes embedded resources (images, scripts, styles, fonts, sounds) from memory or disk cache and JMeter by default makes "clean" request.

Try ticking "Disable cache" box in the "Network" tab of your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Developer_Tools) and you should start getting more or less the same timings:

[image]

You can also add a [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to your test plan but in this case the cache will start working for 2nd request/iteration.

Check out [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) for more tips on configuring JMeter for web applications performance testing.